# Angular MultiSelect dropdown list issue

Tags: html, angular, list, dropdown, multi-select

items is the list that is coming from backend evrything is working fine except the checkbox in dropDown..i am not able to select 1 checkbox as it selects all on clicking 1 cb also.

```
 <div class="form-group">
                    <angular2-multiselect [data]="items"  name="items" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
                    [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
                    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
                    (onDeSelect)="OnItemDeSelect($event)"
                    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
                    (onDeSelectAll)="onDeSelectAll($event)">
                    <c-item >
                        <ng-template let-item="item" >
                        <label style="color: rgb(235, 18, 18);min-width: 150px;">{{item.itemName}}</label>
                        </ng-template>
                    </c-item> 
                </angular2-multiselect>
                </div>
```

Comment: We'll need to have the html/typescript code for your angular2-multiselect component before we can help you. In case this component comes from a package, please post the name of the package

Answer (score 0):

In your 'dropdownSettings', do 'enableCheckAll' false.

Comment: same issue , I think every item should has id but my items come from DB

Comment: In your json data that is coming from db, there must be a unique field key. In 'dropdownSettings', write that keyname against 'primaryKey' field.

Comment: what is the value of PK? every item has id how specify it in PK?

Comment: Consider adding one json item in comments.